# Regex matcher prevent repeated searches of a string

Tags: java, regex

I got this program here to search for conjunctions in a sentence.
I made an array:

```
public static final String[] SUB_CONJS = new String[] {
    "after", "afterwards", "although", "as if",
    "as long as", "as much as", "as soon as",
    "as though", "because", "before", "by the time",
    "even if", "even though", "if", "in order that"...
    //some more    
};
```

As you can see there are repititions such as `"if"` and `"as if"`

I used a matcher to search for them:

```
String toSearch = "(?i)\\b(" + String.join("|", SUB_CONJS) + ")\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(toSearch);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) count++;
```

For example, if I put `"as if"` into `text`, `count` equals 2 because the matcher searched both `"if"` and `"as if"`. Are there methods to solve the problem? thanks

Comment: That will not compile. There is no static `Pattern.matcher()` method.  Never re-type code, always copy/paste into the StackOverflow editor.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening since `"as if"` if before `"if"` in regex so it should consume potential `as if` in text and that should prevent `if` from matching such text. Probably you got in your SUB_CONJS array parts which are less specific than others. You could try to sort this array using `contains` method. If string A contains string B then A should be placed before B in array.

Answer (score 1):

As Pshemo wrote, your code example returns the desired result when testing the string `"as if"`: 1 match.

This is because `"if"` is not a prefix of `"as if"`. In fact, other than Pshermo said, it does not matter in which order `"if"` and `"as if"` appear in your regex, since they are not prefixes of each other.

The matter becomes more complicated when you add `"as"` to your list in front of other terms starting with "as". In this case, the regex actually "consumes" the "as", disregarding potential longer matches.

This is easily fixed by sorting your search terms accordingly before searching:

```
Comparator<String> prefixesLast = (s1, s2) -> {
    if (s1.startsWith(s2)) return -1;
    if (s2.startsWith(s1)) return 1;
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
};
```

or, to make it even simpler, just order by string order, but descending:

```
Comparator<String> descending = (s1, s2) -> return s2.compareTo(s1);
```

Using the sorted list to produce your regex should ensure to always find the longest match.